# Multiple forms in one form play[2.0.4]

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, forms

I am trying to do a form that has one model and 2 values that are always the same but there is one value that changes.

My html form is:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.TeacherController.putQuestionToAssignment(), 'class -> "form-horizontal") {

            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="@{size}">
            <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="@{assignment_id}">
            @for(question <- questions){
                <input type="checkbox" name="question_id" value="@{question.question_id}">
            }
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">create</button>
    }
```

my model:

```
@Entity
public class Verkefnaspurningar extends Model {
    @Id
    public int verkefnaspurningar_id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public int assignment_id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public int question_id;
    @Constraints.Required
    public Double size;
```

and in the controller i am going to try to create a model for each question that is checked in the checkbox in the form, but i have no idea how to do that, can i maybe set an id on the question_id field in the form and loop through that?

```
public static Result putQuestionToAssignment(){
        Form<Verkefnaspurningar> verkefnaspurningarForm = form(Verkefnaspurningar.class).bindFromRequest();
            int question_id= verkefnaspurningarForm.get().question_id;
            Double size= verkefnaspurningarForm.get().size;
            int assignmentId= verkefnaspurningarForm.get().assignment_id;
            Verkefnaspurningar verkefnaspurningar = Verkefnaspurningar.create(assignmentId, question_id, size);

        return redirect(routes.TeacherController.createAssignment());
    }
```

Hoping that this post is not to dumb, my first one, with kind regards Björn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea to the solution for your problem. But, I test this solution using **Play!Framework 2.1.0**.

In your **controller**, you can get the checked `question_id` value submitted by user like this :

```
public static Result putQuestionToAssignment() {
    // get all HTTP request value from submitted form
    Map<String, String[]> map = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
    String[] allCheckedData = map.get("question_id"); // get all checked question
    ... // bind the rest of request parameter to variable if needed

    Verkefnaspurningar verkefnaspurningar;
    // Loop for each checked question
    for (String t : allCheckedData) {
        Logger.info("Checked data is " + t);
        verkefnaspurningar = new Verkefnaspurningar(); // create each data
        ... // put the rest of code for saving the model
    }

    return TODO; // still dummy. Should be redirect!
}
```

Please note that I'm not use `Form` in this solution. I get all the request parameter from submitted form using `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()`. Check documentation for `RequestBody` [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestBody.html).

Comment: Nice, thank you, the "request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()" was exactly what i needed :)

Comment: Please kindly accepted this answer, if it was useful for you by clicking the check sign on this answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a DynamicForm for this. It would be something like:

```
public static Result putQuestionToAssignment(){

        DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();

        Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : form.data().entrySet()) {
                ids.add(Long.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
        }

        Verkefnaspurningar verkefnaspurningar;
        for (Long id : ids) {
                verkefnaspurningar = Verkefnaspurningar.create(assignmentId, id, ids.size());
        }
        return redirect(routes.TeacherController.createAssignment());
}
```

To get the `assignmentId`, you may have to add a condition when looping over `form.data().entrySet()`: if `entry.getKey()` if the one of your assignment, then store id, else add value to Set.